# Exporting a Mathematica Document as LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have tried several times to import a Mathematica document into a Wiki using the "Export As Latex" option.  It never works.

Of course I have the option of copying each stretch of text as text and each non-textual expression as Latex but I might as well just use a TeX editor for all the work that is involved.

Latex is supposed to accept a complete document.  Is there a way to have Mathematica export a complete document that is acceptable to, say, Wikia or Wordpress?

Here is some sample output from Mathematica embedded in a < math >..< /math > pair or ($latex ... $ doesn't work either).

\text{Let the three edges of a tetrahedron with one vertex at the origin be denoted }

e_i, i= 1\text{..}3.

\text{  The face vectors defined by Rovelli are then
$\quad $}

L_1 =\text{  }\frac{1}{2} e_2\times  e_3,

L_2 =\text{  }\frac{1}{2} e_3\times  e_1

\text{, and }

L_3 =\text{  }\frac{1}{2} e_1\times  e_2

\text{.
Note that, for example, }

L_1 \text{and} L_2

\text{are both perpendicular to }

e_3

\text{ so that }

L_1\times L_2

\text{must be parallel to }

e_3.

\text{  In fact
$\quad $}

L_1\times L_2

\text{ = }

\frac{1}{4}

\text{Det}[e]



e_3

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: This is not an issue with *Mathematica*, but with the other platforms you mention. Apparently they don't accept the $\LaTeX$ code you want.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider:

1) Use the menu item 'Save As' and choose and Save as type: Latex Document instead of Export if you need the whole document as mentioned in your question.

2) Make sure you use adequate plug-in for Wordpress or Wiki to render Latex typesetting